# Historical Quotes

Tags: stocks, gnucash, quotes

I imported Quicken data starting at the 1st of last year. Although all of the investment transactions transferred correctly, no security prices were included. I would like to import prices from the beginning of last year.  Can historical stock quotes be imported into Gnucash?